# Delete all the 'junk' that comes when printing a file from the internet

Tags: python, urllib

I want to print a file from the internet that contains `\n` and `b'`

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
data = urlopen('http://willswebdev.000webhostapp.com/plan.txt')
for line in data: 
    print(line)
```

```
b'Hello Series\n'
```

This is the first line, how do I get rid of `b'` and `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting data from the internet, you are getting them in binary `bytes` format, thus the `b` prefix,
 for that part you just convert the binary string to `str` which can be done using the `bytes` `decode` method,
for example

```
>>> var = b'hello world'
>>> type(var)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> svar = var.decode()
>>> type(svar)
<class 'str'>
>>> var
b'hello world'
>>> svar
'hello world'
>>>
```

for the `\n`, it is the newline character, which is what gets inputted into a file when pressing enter on the keyboard, thus a program reading the data knows where a newline should start, and it is the point where python iterates on when you are running `for line in data`,
to remove that you just need to use the `str` method `strip` which removes all non-printable characters, (one of them being said `\n` character).

thus you need to do

```
for line in data:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```